# Invoking servlet after javascript function kills session

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I had the following:

```
<a href="/servlet/MyServlet" onclick="javascript:CreatePageView();"> Link 1 </a>
```

but I noticed that the javascript function CreatePageView() did not get executed all the time and was creating a race situation.  Sometimes the javascript would get executed, others times the redirect was happening first.

So I wanted to control the order of events and thought to invoke the servlet within my javascript function.

```
function CreatePageView()
{
    //Execute javascript function here

    //Invoke servlet here
    document.forms[0].action = "/servlet/MyServlet";
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

When I invoke my servlet, my session gets destroyed and I get redirected to the login page.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?  Or perhaps suggest an alternate method of invoking the servlet without killing the session?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds much like as if that JavaScript is firing an **asynchronous** request. Otherwise the problem doesn't make any sense. The link's action will in any way only be executed when the JavaScript function has returned. But when you're firing an asynchronous/ajaxical request in the JS function, then indeed a race condition may occur. It namely doesn't execute in sync. It executes "in the background".

You need to ensure that the link is only invoked when the asynchronous request is finished. Assuming that you're doing it in "plain vanilla" JS by `XMLHttpRequest` instead of a convenient Ajaxical JS library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), then you need to do the job in the `onreadystatechange`.

Change the link as follows:

```
<a href="/servlets/MyServlet" onclick="return createPageView(this)">
```

*(note that the `javascript:` pseudoprotocol is **unnecessary** and that JS functions usually start with lowercase)*

And fix your JS function as follows (not MSIE compatible, fix that yourself)

```
function createPageView(link) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            window.location = link.href; // See?
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com', true);
    xhr.send(null);
    return false; // Block link's default action.
}
```

---

As to the question why the session get destroyed, it will be "destroyed" when the request headers doesn't contain the proper session cookie, or when you call `session.invalidate()` in server side, or when the request is been fired on a different domain/context. You're the only one who can investigate which one is the culprit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding and clarifying things.  I understand everything in your code example with the exception of the last three lines.  Would I substitute http: // example.com with my servlet URL?

Comment: Just the same URL as you called asynchronously inside your function. You didn't show the entire body of the `CreatePageView()` function, so I just gave an example. Or aren't you firing an asynchronous request in your function at all?

Comment: The problem is the javascript function that I am calling is a 3rd party library used for web analytics (capturing number of times a link is clicked) so I am unsure if it is firing an asynchronous request or not.  Due to the race situation, I would imagine that it is a asynch request.  Can I still use this method to call the function using xhr.open()?

Comment: Oh, that get complicated. Yes, such a JS web analytics thing undoubtely fires an asynchronous request to its host (that would in fact be the URL which you should call). But if you don't have control over its source code, then you can't do any much more. Best what you can do is to introduce a timeout on calling the link's action. Replace the whole `xhr` thing by [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) with, say, 1 second.

Comment: Yes I thought about doing this but still have yet to come up with the exact delay.  I will investigate to see if there is a synchronous version of the function in question.  Well thanks again for your reply.

Comment: Also check if there's an opportunity to pass a so-called callback function. If true, then you could also make use of it.